# Vertical align font awesome icon with text within <li>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

I have a list that uses font awesome, hence its class is `fa-ul` :

```
<ul class='fa-ul'>
      <li class='dept'><i class='fa-li fa fa-stop'></i><span>Management</span></li>
      <li class='dept'><i class='fa-li fa fa-stop'></i><span>Something else</span></li>
</ul>
```

The associated CSS is :

```
li {
    font-size : 2em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

I'd like the text and the stop-square to be vertically aligned. So far, it is not the case :

See screenshot:

[image: See screenshot]

I've tried to wrap the fa-icon and the text in a `<div>` element with `vertical-align` property set to `middle`, without success. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: The <i> and the <span> should be inline-block with vertical-align: middle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `inline-blocks` and do `vertical-align: middle` to make it right.

```css
li {
    font-size : 2em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

li > *{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class='fa-ul'>
      <li class='dept'><i class='fa-li fa fa-stop'></i><span>Management</span></li>
      <li class='dept'><i class='fa-li fa fa-stop'></i><span>Something else</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, it does the trick and even if the alignment is not quite perfect it would be much easier tore-use it

Answer (score 2):

Use **Line-Height**

```
 li {
   font-size: 2em;
   margin: 1em 0;
   line-height: 40px;/*try changing this value*/
 }
```

Comment: thanks, so the alignment strongly depends on what text size I use. Is there a way to achieve that without testing line-height values ?

Answer (score 0):

li { position: absolute; top:0; left:0;}
For the text next to it, use padding left.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31141272)